# Python requests выдаёт 426 status code. А curl и Postman - 200

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, ssl, tls

Пытаюсь сделать запрос через Python requests к 'https://maxmaster.ru', но выдаёт 426 ошибку.

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.25.0'
>>> resp = requests.get('https://maxmaster.ru')
>>> resp.status_code
426
```

Я делал запросы к данному ресурсу через curl и Postman, статус ответа был всегда 200. Подскажите, как добиться этого же ответа, используя Python requests?

Использую Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Python3.9.0

Comment: Postman возвращает 426 ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`426 Upgrade Required` - Вы используете слишком древний http:)

Указанный сайт похоже хочет http/2.0. А питоновская библиотека похоже поддерживает только 1.1 (я бы сказал "классическую версию").

Что делать? использовать библиотеку с поддержкой http2, например https://www.python-httpx.org/http2/ или https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ или найдите/напишите свою.